# What is the idea behind dataset objects and data- attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

What is the benefit of using the `dataset` objects and `data-` attributes? I feel the same thing can be accomplished by extending HTML DOM objects and adding properties to them. (I’m aware this code isn’t exactly reasonable; it’s just a quick example).

There must have been some idea behind adding `data-` objects to the API. Also is there a convention against adding properties to DOM objects or are these two methods equally acceptable? If this is debatable what are the pros and cons to each method?

There is a similar question involving the jquery version data-objects, but I'm assuming .data() operates a bit differently and maybe has different pros and cons associated with it.

```js
//dataset
let input = document.getElementById("userData");

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let value = input.value;
  input.dataset.value = value;
  console.log("input.dataset.value:" + input.dataset.value);
});

//dom objects extending
let input = document.getElementById("userData");

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let value = input.value;
  input.Val = value; //adds properties refering to html object state
  console.log("input.val:" + input.val);
});
```

```html
<div class="userInput">
  <label for="userData">Type Something:</label><input type="text" id="userData">
</div>
```

Comment: Because you can’t predict the future and can’t know when some property will be used for something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing data to DOM - Element value vs data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976440/storing-data-to-dom-element-value-vs-data-attribute)

Comment: ["HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or Node.setUserData()."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can safely extend any html element without knowing 100% of present, past and future html attributes.

It also make html code easier to read, because after seeing

```
<input sync>
```

I might go and search what is this new sync attribute ?

however

```
<input data-sync="true">
```

makes it very clear where it comes from (custom attribute later used in js to add behaviors or styles)

You can then retrieve the value using the DOM dataset API or getAttribute.

It also make it easy to include data with a template based language like PHP.

In a pure javascript settings, I would not use data attributes. WeakMaps allows you to safely extend DOM or you can set a key-value pair directly on the DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

- How were you planning on extending the DOM objects?
- What property(ies) would you extend them with?
- How often would you need to go back and add some new extension?
- How would you keep track of all the extensions?

The answers to these questions should make it clear that by using the `data-*` attribute and then accessing those attribute values with `dataset` make custom extensions of DOM objects unnecessary.

By the way, it is generally considered bad practice to modify the underlying API of any native object/element.